# Is there an online tool for designing kitchen layout?

Tags: kitchens, design

I am looking at having my kitchen replaced. It is a tiny room no bigger than 6ft by 6ft.

I would like to find an online tool that will let me drag and drop appliences and fittings into the room so I can see what it will look like.

The reason is that I am useless at drawing and would like to take something with me to shops etc.

We will not be having a designer come over or a builder install it as my partners dad is capable of doing a good job.

Comment: I tied to use some of these, but was not impressed.   They did not take into about the fact that cupboards can be modified to fix, and that custom shelves to be built to fit in a small space.  I have in the past printed out a set of shapes to scale and then just paid with moving them about on a plan.  Also in the UK, a lot of cupboards makers, e.g. Howdans do a free design service with the ideal that you will then get your builder to buy from them – no cost or commitment to use the service.

Answer (score 2):

I know of these two free tools:

- [One by Ikea](http://kitchenplanner.ikea.com/CA/UI/Pages/VPUI.htm?Lang=en-CA)
- [One by a kitchen cabinet company called Mei](http://www.meikitchens.com/measurement_design/measurement_tool.php)

You might find more by searching "Kitchen layout tool" on Google.

Comment: I did this, but most options require a download, and are as such not online. The Mei one isn't that great as its, quite hard to input specfics.

Answer (score 1):

http://m.lowes.com/mt/www.lowes.com/cd_virtual+room+designer_189310537_

http://www.housebeautiful.com/kitchens/design-your-own-kitchen